# Why did Cooper send coordinates to NASA when just a moment before he saw that he was headed to NASA?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In the closing tesseract scene, why does Cooper write the coordinates to NASA when just a moment before it is clear he knew where his past self (Cooper) was headed (to NASA)? What was the impulse or reason for sending the coordinates again?

In [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27159/if-cooper-wanted-to-stay-why-did-he-send-the-nasa-coordinates/44803#44803), we understand why Cooper still sent the coordinates even though he previously told Murph to stay. **This is not my question**.

In the first tesseract scene, Cooper saw his past self leaving the room to go to NASA, so he clearly knew (inside the tesseract) that Murph and himself already had the coordinates.

To put it another way, why did Cooper send coordinates to NASA when just a moment before he saw that he was headed to NASA? What was his reason for finding an earlier moment in the tesseract to send the coordinates when he could have simply allowed himself to leave to NASA, which happened anyway?

Timeline in the tesseract:

1. Cooper says, "Make him stay, Murph. Don't let me leave, Murph!"

Here we see that tesseract-Cooper clearly knows that bedroom-Cooper is leaving for NASA.

2. Cooper comes to realization in the tesseract and says, "TARS, give me the coordinates for NASA in binary."

Here we see tesseract-Cooper getting the coordinates to a place that bedroom-Cooper was already leaving to in the first scene above. This is my question. Why would he search out an earlier moment in time within the tesseract when it was not only clear to him within the tesseract that his bedroom self was leaving for NASA, but it was also doubly clear in that he had already experienced that very moment in the bedroom. He KNEW they both had the coordinates yet went further back in time in the tesseract to provide the coordinates...

> This [chosen answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/27254/100235) to the above linked question would *almost*
> answer my question if the answer was correct, but it's not, for two
> reasons, which I left in the comment to the answer.

Comment: this answer explains it all https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44803/19762

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If Cooper wanted to stay, why did he send the NASA Coordinates?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27159/if-cooper-wanted-to-stay-why-did-he-send-the-nasa-coordinates)

Comment: No… neither of those answer my question. Read my question. @Luciano

Comment: No @Joachim it does not. Please read again.

Comment: I do agree this is not a duplicate of the linked question. However, it still comes down to the same principle that various other questions already touched upon. The film depicts a closed timeloop and for that to be consistent, Cooper *had* to send the coordinates. If he did so in order to keep the timeline consistent, if he just didn't know and only sent them out of confusion or if he did it to flesh out his theory about the timeline or for any other reason isn't clear. It *had* to happen, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson at least you understand my question. I understand that it had to happen, I just wanted to know the impulse behind it.

Comment: i.e. the answer is he sent them to that time because that's the time he remembered receiving them.

Comment: @OrangeDog right… but that’s my question… the question is why.

Comment: @MichaelRader that is why. It's a classic bootstrap paradox.